# Как узнать длину всех элементов массива в другом массиве

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой массив

```
const users = [
    {
        _id: 'id1',
        name: 'Эндре Хифон',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            },
            {
                _id: '2',
                text: 'Текст2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'id6130f39a3d55b',
        name: 'Факир Валунтас',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'ide72070fe6000d',
        name: 'Клаус Кэнтерберийский',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            },
            {
                _id: '2',
                text: 'Текст2'
            },
            {
                _id: '3',
                text: 'Текст3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Как мне из него получить длину всех texts из всех массивов массива users?

Я пробовал решить так, + разные вариации:

```
const count = users.map((user) => user.texts)  
const countTest = count.flat().reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
console.log(0[object Object][object Object]...)
```

И так:

```
const count = () => {
        users.map((user) => user.texts.map((text) => text.length))
    }
```

Ничего не работает. Подскажите верный способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как мне из него получить длину всех texts из всех массивов массива users?

Например вот так...

```js
const users = [
    {
        _id: 'id1',
        name: 'Эндре Хифон',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            },
            {
                _id: '2',
                text: 'Текст2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'id6130f39a3d55b',
        name: 'Факир Валунтас',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'ide72070fe6000d',
        name: 'Клаус Кэнтерберийский',
        texts: [
            {
                _id: '1',
                text: 'Текст'
            },
            {
                _id: '2',
                text: 'Текст2'
            },
            {
                _id: '3',
                text: 'Текст3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
const l = users.reduce((s, {texts}) => s + texts.length, 0)
console.log(l)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это было одновременно просто и сложно)